# php if a string contain two different characters

Tags: php, string

How can I see if a given string contatin multiple characters that I want to look for? for ex:

```
$manywords = "apple orange pineapple banana cat";
if (!(strstr($manywords, 'apple'||'cat')))
{
    echo "either word found";
}
```

is there a way I can use `strstr` function without having to write it twice as follows:

```
if (!((strstr($manywords, 'apple')||(strstr($manywords, 'cat')))
{
     echo "either word found";
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answers. it helped a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$did_it_match = preg_match('/apple|cat/',$manywords);
```

Comment: rofl I just noticed the question edit as well http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17385506/revisions though yes the original code pointed in that direction as well.

Comment: "the original code pointed in that direction" is the problem: The OP doesn't know what they want, so you can't use the direction of the code to point the right way.

Comment: Exactly, the `echo`ed result and code contradicted each other, anyway one of your answers will have to be the right one.

Comment: I still have 2600 rep to go before I can see deleted answers :( You're a bit closer, glhf.